# Why is my app throwing IllegalStateException GoogleApiClient is not connected yet?

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-api-client

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
```

This is coming from my Service (GetInformationService.onConnected). It is weird how it says it is not connected in my onConnected method? I have seen many questions like this but I could still not figure it out because all of the answers say something about onCreate method but I have no onCreate since this is a service. Here is my relevant code (keep in mind I am extending IntentService):

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    g = Globals.getInstance();
    context = this;


    locationProvider = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(60000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(15000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    googleApiClient.connect();
}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) 
{
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
}
```

Comment: You can still have an onCreate in your service class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including `onCreate()` in your service and build `googApiClient` from here

```
    @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
    googleApiClient.connect();
      }
```

Comment: Should I keep the other code in my original post inside of OnHandleIntent? Or move it all?

Comment: other code is fine. Only the initialization should be done in onCreate()